# How to implement auto-renewable subscription for InApp purchase?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, in-app-purchase, auto-renewing

I have implemented non-consumable subscription in InApp. It is working fine. It shows alert as `You have already purchased blah blah` but I think It is because i have test user account.

When i tried to implement Auto-renewable with the same method it goes to `FailedTransaction` method everytime. with the error `Cannot connect to iTunes Store" UserInfo=0x11a190 {NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot connect to iTunes Store}`

If there is any other method to do then please redirect me. I got the very good steps from this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329336/in-app-auto-renewable-subscriptions) but didn't get any code that how exactly it should be implemented.

Comment: Did you implement that blog code? From that, I am not sure about the cancel method. Is it restorable? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

This will solve all your confusion towards autorenewable subscription https://github.com/MugunthKumar/MKStoreKit

Comment: Can u brief me what exactly the flow is? Is this receipt verification is for auto-renewable only or does it apply for non-consumable too?

Comment: u mean nonconsumable subscription??

Comment: http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/mkstorekit-4-0-supporting-auto-renewable-subscriptions go through this

Comment: i want renewable inapp code for objective-c is it possible??