# Auto-renewable subscription multiple accounts

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

A similar question was already asked here, but wasn't answered. I'm developing iOS application for service that already has its own account system on their website. With your account you can subscribe for premium service to get additional features like high quality videos etc.

I'm trying to implement same functionality in iOS application. If user purchases subsription it has to be connected to his account in the system, not to his Apple ID. And if he logs out and authorizes with another account he cannot use subscription benefits and has to purchase another subscription for second account.

Can I implement this using in-app purchases?

Comment: possible duplicate of [In app auto-renewable subscriptions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329336/in-app-auto-renewable-subscriptions)

Comment: Removed the RMStore tag. RMStore can be used to implement auto-renewable subscriptions, but the question does not seem to be about RMStore in particular.

Comment: @MikeW my question is a bit different. I know I'll have to synchronize with my webservice anyway. I'm wondering if it is possible to buy multiple subscriptions with one AppleID (for different accounts in my webservice)

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? I need to do the same thing on my app.

Comment: @Merkidemis not really. We ended up with simplified system. If a subscription (purchased via AppStore) is active then any user has premium service benefits on this device. If user wants to have this benefits on his website account when using browser then he has to attach his AppStore subscription to his account using specific API (one subscription can be attached to one account only)

Comment: Hey, @Spail did you get the solution? I'm stuck in exactly the same situation as yours

Comment: @RomitKumar check my comment above