# Two Accounts For the price of one. Bug in a subscription app that uses Apple's in app purchase

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

So, I am an iOS Developer, working on an app that has a subscription based model. While going through an app that provides a subscription based service. the app, I seem to have come across a bug in the architecture

So, I got a new iPhone downloaded the app on that device, clicked restore purchases my subscription was restored and all was working fine. 
But, this got me thinking about the entire architecture of the payment system, hence after this I logged out of my current id, registered a new account with a new email, once again, clicked restore purchases and then to my surprise the app recognised me as a premium member on the second email address as well!
And now currently, I have two premium memberships on two different email addresses for the price of one.

So this got me thinking, would there possibly be a way to avoid this kind of scenario for my app?
Or is this a bug that I would have to report to apple?

Comment: The behavior you're seeing is because you already restored purchases on the device with an account that had a subscription, and the developer likely didn't take the necessary steps to check the new account against the receipt. This question might be similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329336/in-app-auto-renewable-subscriptions

Comment: This seems to be a problem with receipts.